# Intricacies of Windows driver signing (re-naming and re-signing OpenVPN tap driver)

Tags: windows, driver, openvpn

I'm unclear how a driver should be signed in my specific circumstances.

OpenVPN has a tap driver that consists of tap0901.sys, tap0901.cat and OemWin2k.inf files.

When I install it using "devcon install OemWin2k.inf tap0901" on my win7 64-bit, it installs silently, without scary warnings.

I renamed the driver to have a different name ogtap100 (by renaming files to ogtap100.sys, ogtap100.cat and replacing "tap0901" strings in OemWin2k.inf to "ogtap100", as per http://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/ManagingWindowsTAPDrivers and comments in OemWin2k.inf).

However, when I run "devcon install OemWin2k.info ogtap100" on the renamed driver, I get big scary warning from Windows that the driver comes from unknown source. It'll install but I plan to ship it as part of my app, so big scary warning is not good.

When I run "signtool verify /v ogtap100.cat", I get: "SignTool Error: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider." even though it also says that root certificate is "Issued to: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA".

I've tried re-signing (signtool sign /f cert.pfx ogtap100.cat) with my own certificate (which works when signing regular .exe files) but I get the same scary warning.

What am I missing?

Can it be sth. to do with catalog (.cat) file?

I've read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463050 but it assumes that I'll generate .cat file myself. I already have .cat file from OpenVPN. Do I have to re-generate it after renaming files and OewmWin2k.inf? If yes, how?

Comment: Krzysztof, it's an old question, but did you solve your driver signing issue? I have a very similar one and wonder whether to build and sign the driver myself or there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

1) Did you ensure that you got the high assurance digicert certificate? The standard one they issue isn't meant for drivers. It is simple to change...
https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/driver-signing-in-windows-using-signtool.htm

2) If you download the Windows 7 DDK and do a little 'reading the intent and the code' as opposed to just following the instructions, you can succeed at building your own driver (cat and sys files), properly renamed and signed. 
 https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BuildingTapWindows

Look at the OemWin2k.inf generated for some strong hints for renaming.  Note: The Time stamp needs to be correct, and it is in (the ridiculous) mm/dd/yyyy format.

3) As for the warning message, at least you can get it to properly display your company name, and Windows will accept (and not disable) the properly signed driver.

Answer (score 0):

For details about driver signing, check out 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/0b00c9d4-dff9-4fbe-b741-768c9b39349c/practical-windows-code-and-driver-signing-discussion?forum=wdk

This is a summery that points to some reference docs. Generating the .cat file from the inf is simple.

Check out the syntax and order of operation. I'm also using a Digicert certificate. make sure you have one issued for driver signing and pay attention to the make sure the cross certificate is correct.

The build script uses the inf2cat method, so if you are following the WHOLE instructions (and searching for the stuff in the settings that the inf didn't tell you about ... look for constants) then you are generating the .cat file.

For my install, I figured that the .sys file should be signed before generating the .cat and signing it.

Also, make sure your pc has all the windows updates. This actually did work to 'fix' a pc that had the same error signature. (It didn't have the required certificate to validate the cross certificate, which it automatically downloaded.)